# How to compare 2 strings if they have spaces?

Tags: java

I'm having some problem with a simple program I'm working on, I just need to ask the user if he wants the regular price or the sale price. And he needs to respond in a string value. Now I know that I just have to use `if(price.equals("sale") == true)`. But the problem comes if I want the user to type something that has spaces in the words, example: `if(price.equals("regular price") == true)` when I the user types in "regular price" I don't get a response I wanted.
I'm also learning Java by the way.

Comment: Use `replaceAll(" ","")`. Also you can just do `if(price.equals("Sale"))`

Comment: Wild guess: are you testing this by running your application on the command line, and doing something like `myapp regular price`?

Comment: Did you actually write some code in which `if(price.equals("regular price") == true)` doesn't work when the user enters "regular price"? There shouldn't be anything wrong comparing spaces, unless the user entered, say, 2 spaces instead of one. By the way, you don't need `== true` in your test since the result is boolean. `if` checks booleans directly: `if(price.equals("regular price"))`.

Comment: is input has different case (e.g. uppercase, lowercase)? if yes you need to convert them to the matching case..

Comment: The real problem here is working out exactly what the requirements are.  What is the full range of inputs the you want to support?  (And what do you not want to accept?) For example, what about "normal"?  "standard"?  "or regular?  Unless you actually put this detail into your question, we can only guess what you need.  Unless you decide what you need, >>you<< can't implement it.

Comment: *"when the user types in "regular price" I don't get a response I wanted"* Is that perhaps because you're using `scanner.next()`, which only returns one word, even though user typed two words? If so, use `nextLine()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java equals() method/function  works perfectly with the spaces too. Also you don't need to compare the result with true/false. If two string is equal then equals() will automatically return true else it will return false.

```
 public class MyClass {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         String a = "A B C";
         if(a.equals("A B C")){
             System.out.println("YES");
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("NO");
         }
     }
 }
```

I tested the following program and it returned true while the string has spaces in it.

Comment: My bad, the mistake was that I put == at the end, didn't knew I didn't have to check if its true or false and that would automatically return the value. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if a string *contains* a word like this:

```
if (price.toLowerCase().contains("regular"))
```

If you want to get fancy, you can use regex to match a whole word (eg not "irregular"):

```
if (price.matches("(?i).*\\bregular\\b.*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare strings with spaces right?
Then you can first compare their lengths, then

If string contains `space` split it by it, again compare lengths, next check every string.

If it not contains space, just use `equals` once, here what i come up with:

```
class cmp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "test some";
        String s2 = "test some";
        String s3 = "test not";
        String s4 = "testxsome";
        System.out.println(cmpStr(s,s2)); // True
        System.out.println(cmpStr(s,s3)); // False
        System.out.println(cmpStr(s,s4)); // False
    }
    public static  boolean cmpStr(String str1, String str2) {
        if (str1.length() != str2.length()) {
            System.out.println("Length mismatch.");
            return false;
        }
        if (str1.contains(" ") || str2.contains(" ")) {
            String[] a1 = str1.split(" ");
            String[] a2 = str2.split(" ");
            if (a1.length != a2.length) {
                System.out.println("Split Length mismatch.");
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
                if (!a1[i].equals(a2[i])) {
                    System.out.println("One of split mismatch." + a1[i]  + " " + a2[i] );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!str1.equals(str2)) {
                System.out.println("Regular equals returns false.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I see three methods

- Remove all the spaces and hidden characters from the string and check

  ```
  String  input = "regular price";        
  input = input.replaceAll("\\s+","");    
  if(price.equals(input))
  {
     //your code here
  }
  ```
- Check whether the word contains keywords

  ```
  if (price.toLowerCase().contains("regular"))
  ```
- Create a regular expression to match your words